# Python Pony Orm Test if table is empty

Tags: python, database, ponyorm

I would like to test if a table is empty using pony orm.

At first I connect to the database and say generate mappings.
I'm using the 'Names' table as an example here and connect to a postgres database

```
from pony.orm import *

class Names(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)


@db_session
def populate_names(name_list):
    for name_element in name_list:
        db.insert("Names", name=name_element)


@db_session
def test_empty():
    temp = False
    # if Names is empty, set temp = True
    if Names ... :
        temp = True

    return temp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    characters = ['James', 'Elisabeth', 'Paul', ...]

    db = Database()
    db.bind(provider='postgres', user='', password='', host='', database='')

    # generate_mappings already creates empty tables
    db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

    empty = test_empty()

    if empty is True:
        populate_names(characters)
```

I couldn't find anything in the Pony Docs about checking if a table is empty.

```
if Names is None:
```

The line above gives me 'False' because the table already exists.
Does anyone know a solution to that?

Comment: It would always return an empty list and hence it is not none. Try checking the length of the list if it is zero

Comment: @mad_ Do you mean applying a SELECT query to the table and see if the list returned from it, is none?

Comment: How do you intend to check? You can either check from the active session or from the db. Either ways you have to query(in order to update the session contents) the db table. Just fire query(Names).all() and check the length of the returned list

Comment: @mad_ Thanks for the help. I could fix it like that: if not Names.select_random(1):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to write:

```
with db_session:
    if not Names.select().exists():
        populate_names()
```

Alternatively you can put test inside `populate_my_entity()`:

```
@db_session
def populate_names(name_list):
    if Names.select().exists():
        return
    for name_element in name_list:
        db.insert("Names", name=name_element)
```